# iOS SDK - using @2x, and icons.. where do they go?

Tags: ios, graphics, icons, app-store

I have been developing my app for about a week and have loaded some images into it.

I noticed that you can put an image into the app and it scales correctly.  I have some larger images that have scaled down and look great.

I guess this is discouraged because it takes some processing power or memory correct?  Okay, so I want to scale my images to their actual size.

Let's say I have a button that is 40x50

Should that be the @2x size, or should I double that, and set that to the @2x size?

Second question is:  I read apple guidelines about submissions to the app store, and it looks like you need to submit a plethora of icons.  I know you can apply a retina icon, and a regular icon when setting up your project.  What about the rest.  do you just use their naming guidelines and dump them into your project somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

> should that be the @2x size, or should I double that, and set that to the @2x size?

Listen to your intuition. It's not called `image@0.5x` but `image@2x`...

> do you just use their naming guidelines and dump them into your project somewhere?

After your graphics designer has sent you the necessary files, yes. But not just "somewhere". Rather into the root of your app bundle.

Comment: okay so the images should be twice as large as the dimensions specified for a selected element?

would the supporting files folder work?

Comment: @hamobi 1. Yes, the retina images have double the resolution. 2. Yes, but that's not really a folder, that's just a group. Xcode is so silly it doesn't reflect the actual filesystem structure in its project view...